# selenium .sendKeys("text") text dissapears after entering

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium

i started learning selenium and have encoutered problem with my assignement.

this is problematic html block

```html
<body>
  <div class="inputs-14Hc7m">
    <div tabindex="1">
      <div>
        <div class="select-2TCrqx inputMonth-IGgn-0">
          <div class="css-1kj8ui-container">
            <div class="css-gvi9bl-control">
              <div class="css-1hwfws3">
                <div class="css-o3gndj-placeholder">Select</div>
                <div class="css-eo20y5">
                  <div class="" style="display: inline-block;">
                    <input
                      autocapitalize="none"
                      autocomplete="off"
                      autocorrect="off"
                      id="react-select-2-input"
                      spellcheck="false"
                      tabindex="0"
                      type="text"
                      aria-autocomplete="list"
                      aria-label="Month"
                      style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 2px; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0px center; border: 0px none; font-size: inherit; opacity: 1; outline: currentcolor none 0px; padding: 0px; color: inherit;"
                      value=""
                    />
                    <div
                      style='position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 18px; font-family: Whitney, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;'
                    ></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="css-1fhf191">
                <div aria-hidden="true" class="css-ku6vh5-indicatorContainer">
                  <svg
                    height="20"
                    width="20"
                    viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                    focusable="false"
                    class="css-19bqh2r"
                  >
                    <path
                      d="M4.516 7.548c0.436-0.446 1.043-0.481 1.576 0l3.908 3.747 3.908-3.747c0.533-0.481 1.141-0.446 1.574 0 0.436 0.445 0.408 1.197 0 1.615-0.406 0.418-4.695 4.502-4.695 4.502-0.217 0.223-0.502 0.335-0.787 0.335s-0.57-0.112-0.789-0.335c0 0-4.287-4.084-4.695-4.502s-0.436-1.17 0-1.615z"
                    ></path>
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div tabindex="2">
      <div>
        <div class="select-2TCrqx inputDay-18OXiE">
          <div class="css-1kj8ui-container">
            <div class="css-gvi9bl-control">
              <div class="css-1hwfws3">
                <div class="css-o3gndj-placeholder">Select</div>
                <div class="css-eo20y5">
                  <div class="" style="display: inline-block;">
                    <input
                      autocapitalize="none"
                      autocomplete="off"
                      autocorrect="off"
                      id="react-select-3-input"
                      spellcheck="false"
                      tabindex="0"
                      type="text"
                      aria-autocomplete="list"
                      aria-label="Day"
                      style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 2px; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0px center; border: 0px none; font-size: inherit; opacity: 1; outline: currentcolor none 0px; padding: 0px; color: inherit;"
                      value=""
                    />
                    <div
                      style='position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 18px; font-family: Whitney, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;'
                    ></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="css-1fhf191">
                <div aria-hidden="true" class="css-ku6vh5-indicatorContainer">
                  <svg
                    height="20"
                    width="20"
                    viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                    focusable="false"
                    class="css-19bqh2r"
                  >
                    <path
                      d="M4.516 7.548c0.436-0.446 1.043-0.481 1.576 0l3.908 3.747 3.908-3.747c0.533-0.481 1.141-0.446 1.574 0 0.436 0.445 0.408 1.197 0 1.615-0.406 0.418-4.695 4.502-4.695 4.502-0.217 0.223-0.502 0.335-0.787 0.335s-0.57-0.112-0.789-0.335c0 0-4.287-4.084-4.695-4.502s-0.436-1.17 0-1.615z"
                    ></path>
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div tabindex="3">
      <div>
        <div class="select-2TCrqx inputYear-2J502p">
          <div class="css-1kj8ui-container">
            <div class="css-gvi9bl-control">
              <div class="css-1hwfws3">
                <div class="css-o3gndj-placeholder">Select</div>
                <div class="css-eo20y5">
                  <div class="" style="display: inline-block;">
                    <input
                      autocapitalize="none"
                      autocomplete="off"
                      autocorrect="off"
                      id="react-select-4-input"
                      spellcheck="false"
                      tabindex="0"
                      type="text"
                      aria-autocomplete="list"
                      aria-label="Year"
                      style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 2px; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0px center; border: 0px none; font-size: inherit; opacity: 1; outline: currentcolor none 0px; padding: 0px; color: inherit;"
                      value=""
                    />
                    <div
                      style='position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 18px; font-family: Whitney, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;'
                    ></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="css-1fhf191">
                <div aria-hidden="true" class="css-ku6vh5-indicatorContainer">
                  <svg
                    height="20"
                    width="20"
                    viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                    focusable="false"
                    class="css-19bqh2r"
                  >
                    <path
                      d="M4.516 7.548c0.436-0.446 1.043-0.481 1.576 0l3.908 3.747 3.908-3.747c0.533-0.481 1.141-0.446 1.574 0 0.436 0.445 0.408 1.197 0 1.615-0.406 0.418-4.695 4.502-4.695 4.502-0.217 0.223-0.502 0.335-0.787 0.335s-0.57-0.112-0.789-0.335c0 0-4.287-4.084-4.695-4.502s-0.436-1.17 0-1.615z"
                    ></path>
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="marginTop20-3TxNs6">
    <button
      type="submit"
      class="button-3k0cO7 button-38aScr lookFilled-1Gx00P colorBrand-3pXr91 sizeLarge-1vSeWK fullWidth-1orjjo grow-q77ONN"
    >
      <div class="contents-18-Yxp">Continue</div>
    </button>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Java Code:**

```java
driver.findElement(By.id("react-select-2-input")).sendKeys(month);
driver.findElement(By.id("react-select-3-input")).sendKeys(day);
driver.findElement(By.id("react-select-4-input")).sendKeys(year);
driver.findElement(By.id("react-select-4-input")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

thing is, after sending month i can see as it is entered and as day box is filled month box get empty. ive checked it like hundred times and still cant see anything. text is copied and is as required from options so it cant be wrong input. also it happens only with first, not with second as i fill third box.

and little subquestion since i got myself here :) second block in html is confirmation button but i cant click it. i did try code that is shown up and also finding it By.tagName("button") and By.className("class="marginTop20-3TxNs6"") ...seems like className cant be with spaces as is in button tag class.

bless you good helpers :) :D

Comment: don't know why the first field is clearing, but for the submit, you can try Selenium's .submit() method an any form element:  https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Submit.htm